# Lambda returns empty string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, lambda

I have a class Fee.

```
class Fee
{
private:
    std::string _code;
    int _value;
    std::string _description_EN;
    std::string _description_UA;
    std::vector<std::function<std::string()>> get_description;
public:
    //CONSTRUCTORS
    Fee(int value, std::string_view code, std::string_view description_EN, std::string_view description_UA);
    Fee(const std::string _csv_line, const char separator);
    Fee(const Fee &) = delete;
    Fee(Fee &&) = default;
    //OPERATORS
    Fee &operator=(const Fee &) = delete;
    Fee &operator=(Fee &&) = default;
    Fee &operator++() = delete;
    Fee &operator++(int) = delete;
    Fee &operator--() = delete;
    Fee &operator--(int) = delete;
    Fee &operator+(const Fee &other) = delete;
    Fee &operator-(const Fee &other) = delete;
    Fee &operator+=(const Fee &other) = delete;
    Fee &operator-=(const Fee &other) = delete;
    Fee &operator/(const Fee &other) = delete;
    Fee &operator*(const Fee &other) = delete;
    Fee &operator/=(const Fee &other) = delete;
    Fee &operator*=(const Fee &other) = delete;
    Fee &operator%(const Fee &other) = delete;
    Fee &operator%=(const Fee &other) = delete;
    //SETTERS
    void set_new_value(int value);
    //GETTERS
    std::string code();
    int value();
    std::string description(Language language = Language::EN);
    //FUNCTIONS

    //DESTRUCTOR
    ~Fee() = default;
};
```

And class FeeList which stores map of Fees

```
class FeeList
{
private:
    std::map<std::string, Fee> _fee_list;
    FeeList() = default;
public:
    static FeeList &fee_list();
    //CONSTRUCTORS
    FeeList(const FeeList &) = delete;
    FeeList(FeeList &&) = delete;
    //OPERATORS
    FeeList &operator=(const FeeList &) = delete;
    FeeList &operator=(FeeList &&) = delete;
    //SETTERS

    //GETTERS
    Fee &fee(const std::string &code);
    //FUNCTIONS
    void addFee(Fee &fee);
    void from_csv_file(const std::string &inv_file, const std::string &um_file, const std::string &id_file, const std::string &tr_file, const char separator);
    //DESTRUCTOR
    ~FeeList() = default;

};
```

The constructor of class Fee has the following lines of code which fill up the "get_description" vector by lambdas

```
get_description.resize(2);
    get_description[static_cast<size_t>(fee::Language::EN)] = [this]()->std::string{return _description_EN;};
    get_description[static_cast<size_t>(fee::Language::UA)] = [this]()->std::string{return _description_UA;};
```

Those lambdas are invoked by function "description(fee::Language::)" which should return description inappropriate language.
Implementation is quite straight forward

```
std::string fee::Fee::description(Language language)
{
    return get_description[static_cast<size_t>(language)]();
}
```

The problem is that the empty string is returned from lambda.
I have created simple class to test such an approach and it worked as expected. I can't figure out were is the problem. I'm getting values of other variables (code and value) so the object is stored correctly.

EDIT: Here is a link to coliru.stacked-crooked.com with my code pasted and worked with mentioned issue (int value; and string code; is Ok string description; is empty) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc56eb53400bd1af
This file can be also found using the Coliru command line: cat /Archive2/bc/56eb53400bd1af/main.cpp

Comment: Probably dangling reference due to `[this]` in lambda. What do you think happens with `this` pointer in case: [1] Fee is created, [2] fee is moved into map of `FeeList`. [3] lambda are invoked on fee from map. Hard to tell without seeing MCVE.

Comment: Hi Mitya, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve] (something we could paste to e.g. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ and see the problem outselves).

Comment: better design is to have `std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Fee>>` or `shared_ptr`, then you won't have to worry about objects moving around.

Comment: I was considering unique_ptr. Had included <memory>. But firstly would like to handle the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

The implicitly-instantiated `Fee` move constructor copies over the lambdas in `get_description` - but it doesn't reach inside those lambdas and update the pointer they have captured. They still point to the original `Fee` object, which has been moved from. Your program then exhibits unspecified behavior by way of accessing moved-from objects.

Instead of having two individual string variables and a vector of lambdas, why don't you just have a vector of strings?

Comment: Thank you for clarification. And thank for good idea with vector of strings.

Comment: Maybe you can suggest the way to deal with such behavior of lambdas. For future cases. How can we get inside Kansas with user defined move constructor.

Comment: The solution would rather depend on what you are using lambdas for in those future cases. In the present example, they are completely unnecessary. But if for some reason you are intent on using them here, one possible solution would be to avoid capturing `this`, but instead have them take `Fee*` as a parameter.